# Creating command as service in symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, service, command

I'm trying to register a command class as service in Symfony. When I run bin/console I get the following error:

```
In App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php line 644:

Attempted to load class "Runner" from namespace "App\Command\Circuit".  
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

This is how I register the service:

```
services:
    App\Command\Circuit\Runner:
        tags:
            - { name: 'console.command', command: 'run' }
```

And this is what the command class looks like:

```
namespace App\Command\Circuit;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Runner extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('run');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $time = time();
        file_put_contents("{$time}.txt", 'test');
    }
}
```

I followed [the symfony tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html) but i'm sure there's something I forgot wiring this service.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` and then try the command again

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately without result.

Comment: PHP version?  You could be the victim of some of the preloading issues caused by early versions of 7.4.  And I assume you actually have a directory called App\Command\Circuit?  Also, if your are using the default service configuration then there is no need to register your command.

Comment: I use php 7.4 and the directory is correct. When I remove the Circuit folder and put the class directly into Command I still haven the same error except the exception is "App\Command"

Comment: Which specific version of 7.4.x?  Upgrade to 7.4.4 if possible.  7.4.0 and 7.4.1 has issues.

Comment: @Cerad I upgraded to 7.4.4 but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you copy/paste your code directly into the question?  If so then the missing semi-colon in configure is causing the somewhat misleading error message.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: I suppose you could try deleting the var/cache directory.  I copied your command code into a fresh 5.0 project and it all worked as expected.

Comment: At this point, I would create a fresh 5.x project, copy in just the Runner.php file and see what happens.  Sure seems like a caching issue of some kind.

Comment: I reinstalled symfony and it helped! thanks for the help